# Resize thumbnail blogger s72-c resolution

Tags: blogger

I have a blogspot webpage `www.f1fanklub.pl` with hot posts script but sometimes it shows low quality thumbnail. I know that there is `/s72-c/` in that kind of thumbnail but I would like to have a script that would change it to `/w680/`

```html
<img class="post-thumb" alt="Wyniki 3 treningu przed GP Brazylii 2019" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-p2EME_z5_So/Xd5sIggTleI/AAAAAAAF980/s5ml9vk7TT8pvewlBG4FN37QOOTaoS_UACLcBGAsYHQ/s72-c/1.jpg" />
```

I tried some scripts from stackoverflow for popular posts on blogger but they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery code:

```js
$('img.post-thumb').each(function(){
    var new_src = $(this).attr('src').replace('/s72-c/','/w680/');
    $(this).attr('src', new_src );
});
```